# Structured Streaming Job not using all workers

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-2.0, spark-structured-streaming

I have a Spark 2.0.2 structured streaming job connecting to Apache Kafka data stream as the source. The job takes in Twitter data (JSON) from Kafka and uses CoreNLP to annotate the data with things like sentiment, parts of speech tagging etc.. It works well with a `local[*]` master. However, when I setup a stand alone Spark cluster, only one worker gets used to process the data. I have two workers with the same capability.

Is there something I need to set when submitting my job that I'm missing. I've tried setting the `--num-executors` in my `spark-submit` command but I have had no luck.

Thanks in advance for the pointer in the right direction.

Comment: You mean that Spark does not **partition** the RDD correctly, so that it does not distribute the load evenly on the executors? Then you may want to specify how to partition on start-up, in your code -- see https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/content/spark-rdd-partitions.html for instance

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating the kafka source stream with more partitions. This seems to have sped up the processing part 9 folds. Spark and kafka have a lot of knobs. Lots to sift through... See [Kafka topic partitions to Spark streaming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37810709/kafka-topic-partitions-to-spark-streaming)